# Keeping object alive by a lambda

Tags: c#, memory-management, lambda, garbage-collection

Let's inspect the following scenario (translating events):

```
public void HookSpecificButton(SpecificButton specificButton, EventHandler eh)
{
    specificButton.SpecificClick += (o, e) => eh(o, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The whole point of the code is to translate event from one type to another: I don't care about data passed by the `specificButton` through `SpecificClick` and I want to attach to this event regular EventHandler.

My question is the following. `eh` contains a reference to method of some object. If there's no other reference to that object, will the lambda be enough for that object to be kept alive? The chain is:

`specificButton` keeps alive an instance of `EventHandler<SpecificData>`, which keeps alive `(lambda)` which keeps alive **(?)** an instance of `EventHandler`, which keeps alive the final object.

Comment: Yes, it's enough. The GC will never collect objects that are still in use

Comment: In this context; "eh" contains a reference to method of some object - can you elaborate on that? It captures the function call eh.

Comment: `eh` is a delegate - a container for method references. But each method has to be called in some context, so the delegate contains a reference to method *and* to some instance, which is owner of that method.

Comment: That lambda is elevated into a class at compile time. Therefore, the actual rooted object is an instance of that class.

Comment: Can you tell us why you care? Normally what the GC does is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object *will* remain alive.  It is still "rooted" because there is a chain of object references from the button to the object containing the method referred to by `eh`.

As per Simon Whitehead's comment on your question, it's interesting how the compiler translates this code.  Take this expansion of your code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        HookSpecificButton(this.MyButton, this.OnButtonClicked);
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public static void HookSpecificButton(Button specificButton, EventHandler eh)
    {
        specificButton.Click += (o, e) => eh(o, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The line where the `Click` event handler is hooked up is actually shorthand for:

```
        specificButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((o, e) => eh(o, EventArgs.Empty));
```

This spells out that you're actually creating a `RoutedEventHandler` delegate object.  A delegate (for a non-static method call) wraps a reference to a target object and a reference to an instance method of that object.

We can examine what happens to the lambda expression using ILDasm.  I see a nested class inside `MainWindow` called `<>c__DisplayClass1`.  This class has a field called `eh` of type `EventHandler` and a method that takes an `object` and a `RoutedEventArgs`.

So we have the following references:

- `Button` *MyButton* -> `RoutedEventHandler`
- `RoutedEventHandler` -> `<>c__DisplayClass1`
- `<>c__DisplayClass1` -> `EventHandler` *eh*
- `EventHandler` *eh* -> `MyWindow` (`OnButtonClicked`)

Here's the ILDasm output for the nested child class of `MainWindow`:

```
  .class auto ansi sealed nested private beforefieldinit '<>c__DisplayClass1'
         extends [mscorlib]System.Object
  {
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
    .field public class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler eh
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void  .ctor() cil managed
    {
      // Code size       7 (0x7)
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  ldarg.0
      IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
      IL_0006:  ret
    } // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig instance void 
            '<HookSpecificButton>b__0'(object o,
                                       class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) cil managed
    {
      // Code size       18 (0x12)
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  ldarg.0
      IL_0001:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler ObjectLifetimeTest.MainWindow/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::eh
      IL_0006:  ldarg.1
      IL_0007:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs [mscorlib]System.EventArgs::Empty
      IL_000c:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.EventHandler::Invoke(object,
                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs)
      IL_0011:  ret
    } // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass1'::'<HookSpecificButton>b__0'

  } // end of class '<>c__DisplayClass1'
```

Of course, in my example the supplied event handler is rooted anyway, because it's in the `Window` itself.  But even if that were not the case, it wouldn't be GC'd.

This means that you get the behaviour you actually want.  But in many, many applications it's a gotcha that causes memory leaks.  It's the reason why it is so important to write code to unsubscribe from events, or use the weak event pattern.